# libopencv_java249.so requires libopencv_java245.so also?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am trying to deploy an opencv java application with opencv 2.49, I have build the **libopencv_java249.so** and **opencv-249.jar** in the **Ubuntu** server and these are available in the class path when the application starts.

But it's throwing a exception saying **libopencv_java245 not found**, so initially I was under a impression that it's referring to a wrong opencv version. so to verify this I have removed the libopencv_java249.so from class path and then it was complaining that libopencv_java249 not available.

As an additional testing I also renamed libopencv_java249.so to libopencv_java245.so then it was saying again that opencv_java249 not found.

With this I guess we can confirm that it looks for the right version of opencv (that is libopencv_java249) but in addition to that it aslo requires libopencv_java245 also. Is my assumption is correct, it would be really helpful if someone can guide me.

Comment: seems it's due to another library we use specifically looks for opencv opencv_java245 , willl do some more research and update the thread

Comment: I could confirm this is due to a another library which looks for opencv_java245....
This question can be closed.